# SCS Kafka consumer processing only latest messages

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am using SCS 1.3.0.RELEASE. I have a producer and a consumer applications. Without starting a consumer application I used producer application to send few messages. Then started the consumer application but the messages were not consumed. When both are up consumer application is processing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the consumer has no `spring.cloud.stream.<...>.group` property, consumption will begin at the end of the topic by default.

Add a group.